# Seeking: Ketavim Hadashim from Rabbi Haim Vital

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Does anyone know where I could get all the Ketavim Hadashim from Rabbi Haim Vital? I am looking for all of the newly published writings in one book. I remember seeing somewhere that it was all in one volume. Does anyone know any stores that have it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is available at www.nehora.com for $29.99 or you can call them at 1-866-463-4672

Comment: Actually, I was looking for Es HaDaat HaTov (I think that's what it's called) and I found it! Thank you. Great site and great variety.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the libraries of [the Hebrew University](http://aleph520.huji.ac.il/F/-?func=full-set-set&set_number=015547&set_entry=000001&format=999), [Indiana University](http://iucat-alt.iu.edu/uhtbin/cgisirsi/X/0/0/5/?searchdata8=OCM21526981), [the University of Chicago](https://libcat.uchicago.edu/ipac20/ipac.jsp?uri=full=3100001~!1114903~!7&ri=4&aspect=subtab15), [the University of Toronto](http://search2.library.utoronto.ca/UTL/coverflow.jsp?item_id=39160819090082), [the University of Florida](http://uf.catalog.fcla.edu/uf.jsp?ix=nu&st=21526981&V=D&S=2501324925155599&I=0), [Yale University](http://neworbis.library.yale.edu/vwebv/search?searchCode=GKEY%5E%2a&recCount=50&searchType=1&searchArg=OCM21526981), and [UCLA](http://melvyl.worldcat.org/oclc/21526981).